# What's a "summer-funeral hit"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, british-english, phrase-meaning, is-it-a-phrase

In a YouTube comment commenting on Jamala's song [1944](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1944_(song)), someone says

> You guys enjoy your **summer-funeral hit**! I have nothing else to add.﻿

after saying

> Ukraine should't have won! What a stupid, political contest. Economically and politically insignificant countries will never have the chance to win, even when they send a powerhouse such as Iveta Mukuchyan.  They should've banned that **funeral song**. It's ridiculous. What's next, a holocaust song?﻿

In case context matters, the user seems to be British, based on their user profile, though they could be of Russian descent based on their name.

What's a summer-funeral hit? Doing a search for "summer funeral" didn't get any results in onelook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the wrong combination of words.

There's something called a [summer hit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_hit):

> In the entertainment industry, a summer hit is a song that is released
>   and peaks in its popularity during summer and often later quickly
>   fades away.[2](http://www.bible.gen.nz/amos/culture/funerals.htm#997467) In some years, a single pop song will gain widespread
>   international popularity during the summer holiday season, becoming
>   that summer's definitive summer hit in many countries. Many of the
>   best-known summer hits emerge from outside the British and American
>   pop music industries.
>
> Songs that are marketed to be summer hits are very common, and often
>   feature an upbeat tempo and descriptions of things such as relaxation
>   outdoors and beach parties. These are songs considered ideal listening
>   during summer activities. These intentional summer hits are most
>   common in country (particularly country pop) and mainstream popular
>   music but are much less common in rock.
>
> The opposite of a summer hit in the music industry would be a
>   Christmas song, a category that usually incorporates general winter
>   songs as well.

As an antipodean who celebrates Christmas during summer, I haven't heard of this term before.

There's also something called a [funeral song](http://www.bible.gen.nz/amos/culture/funerals.htm#997467), which is a song sung at a funeral. There's no meaningful matches for "funeral hit", because the commenter is being sarcastic, implying that funeral songs, or a song about a very sad topic, can't chart in the top 40.